# Simulating Keyboard Input

Tags: java, macos

Im working on a project in which  the program will change spaces (on MaxOSX) every couple of minutes. I was wondering whats the best language to use for this (i was thinking java) and what would be the best way to approach this problem. Thanks!

Comment: "*Change spaces*"? Clarify please. Details are important you know.

Comment: He's talking about "Spaces" a Leopard and Snow Leopard feature of having multiple desktops that can be changed using command keys.

Comment: @hatunike: thank you for the clarification. wonder why alex didn't do this?

Comment: yeh sorry i should of been more specific. Is there anyway to periodically press Command + ->

Answer (score 1):

I think using Mac OSX's built in Automator would be significantly easier than writing a java program.

If you are unaware of what this program does, check it out. It's really great for doing automated tasks involving your systems software.

I'd recommend doing the "Watch me do" automation, where it records what you do and then you can run that based on the specific parameters (like very 10 seconds or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be to use Java's Robot class (java.awt.Robot). It has functionality to simulate key presses and mouse clicks .